# Excel vba .Find() function on a list of dates which appear as #

Tags: excel, vba, find

I'm currently working in a spreadsheet that has a row of dates, but all of the dates appear as a # because the column widths are too narrow. I am trying to perform a find function but it only works if the columns are wide enough to see the dates.

I have a work around using a loop, but there are many hundreds if not thousands of dates to look through everytime I call the function so it's seriously bogging me down.

Does anyone know if it is possible to use the .Find function without the dates actually being vissible as dates? I unfortunately cannot widen the columns enough given formating conerns and need to be able to access the data stored in the rows underneath by date.

Answer (score 1):

Change the parameter LookIn:=xlvalues to LookIn:=xlFormulas

```
Sub Macro1()

    'Will find dates showing ##### where column width is not wide enough
    Set a = Sheet1.Range("A:A").Find(What:=#8/22/2013#, LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
        LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
        MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
    Debug.Print a.Address

    'Error on dates showing ##### where column width is not wide enough
    Set a = Sheet1.Range("A:A").Find(What:=#8/22/2013#, LookIn:=xlValues, _
        LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
        MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
    Debug.Print a.Address
End Sub
```